# SwiftUI Clicking on one Row in a List, sets every row on that list to true

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, list, swiftui

I have a List that looks like that:

[image]

But when I click on one row, every circle in every row gets activated/deactivated. I am sitting on that problem for a few Hours now and don't know what to do. Can anyone help me?

I think the problem has something to do with the `DispatchQueue.main.async` Line. But if I don't use `DispatchQueue.main.async` in the code, the list is empty and cannot be filled. And if I wouldn't do `DispatchQueue.main.async`, I get the following Error twice:

`Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.`

So if I use `DispatchQueue.main.async` the list can be filled and is not empty. But as I described earlier, the new Problem is, that when I click a Row, every Circle(from all rows) in the list gets activated/deactivated.

This is my code:

```
struct zettelDetailView: View {
    
    var info: CreateInfo
    
    @State var isChecked: Bool = false
    
    func toggle(){
        isChecked = !isChecked
    }
    
    @State var listItems = [CreateZettelDetailViewText]()
    @State var executeThisAsyncThing: Bool = true

    
        private func changeInfoListToArray() {
            
            //String ist folgendermaßen aufgebaut:
            //"Text/-t;" t = true; f = false "/-" und ";" sind splitter
    //        var returnArray = [CreateZettelDetailViewText]()
            
    //        let infoStr = info.list
            let infoStr = "Das-t;Ist-f;Ein-f;Test-t;"
            
            let infoArr1 = infoStr.split(separator: ";")
            
            var infoArr2 = [[String]]()
            
            print(infoArr1.count)
            
            if infoArr1.count != 0 {
                for i in 0...(infoArr1.count - 1) {
                    let x = infoArr1[i]
                    
                    let y = x.split(separator: "-")[0] //text
                    let z = x.split(separator: "-")[1] //bool
                    
                    var arr2 = [String]()
                    arr2.append(String(y))
                    arr2.append(String(z))

                    var zBool: Bool = false
                    if z == "t" {
                        zBool = true
                    } else if z == "f" {
                        zBool = false
                    }
                    
                    infoArr2.append(arr2)
                    
                    self.listItems.append(CreateZettelDetailViewText(text: "\(String(y))", isDone: zBool))
                    
                }
                            
            }
            
            executeThisAsyncThing = false

        }
    
    

    
    var body: some View {
        
//        listItems = changeInfoListToArray()
        

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          if self.executeThisAsyncThing {
              self.changeInfoListToArray()
          }
      }
            
        
        return VStack {
            
            VStack {
                Text(info.name)
                   .font(.largeTitle)
                Text("\(info.day) - \(info.time)")
            }.offset(y: -50)
            
            
            List(listItems) { a in

                Button(action: self.toggle
//                    {
//
//                    if a.isDone {
//                        self.isChecked = true
//                    } else if !a.isDone {
//                        self.isChecked = false
//                    }
//
//                    print()
//                    print(a.id)
//                    print(a.text)
//                    print(a.isDone)
//                    print()
//
//                }
                ){
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: self.isChecked ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                        Text(a.text)
                    }
                }.onAppear() {
                    self.isChecked = true
                }

            }.offset(y: -50)


            Button(action: addRow) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
                    .offset(y: -20)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }




        }
        
    }
    
        private func addRow() {
                    
//            var arr = [[String]]()
//            arr = getZettelData()
//            arr.append(["ZettelName", "\(time)", "\(day)"])
//
//            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
//            defaults.set(arr, forKey: "SavedZettelArray")

        }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one `isChecked` for the entire list. Each row is using the same variable and so when one of them is tapped, all of them change.

Based on the code it looks like each item in the list has an `isDone` member. Try replacing `self.isChecked` with `a.isDone` for the Image name. Then try changing the button action from `self.toggle` to `{ a.isDone.toggle() }`

So you're List would look like the following.

```
List(listItems) { a in
    Button(action: { 
        a.isDone.toggle()
    }){
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: a.isDone ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
            Text(a.text)
        }
    }
}.offset(y: -50)
```

Comment: This could've been posted as a comment. Add the method to fix OP's issue in your answer.

Comment: I agree. However, I don't have enough rep to comment. I'll add more to my response to make it a solution.

Comment: There is a new component in the beta version of SwiftUI called `Label` which has an image and text together. Can basically be used instead of the `HStack`. Does depend on the version of SwiftUI used though :)

Comment: I tried your solution, but It didn't worked for me because `Cannot assign to property: 'a' is a 'let' constant` do you have any Idea how I can toggle my `a` ?